# On boot, black screen says "Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS [ubuntu name] tty1" and asks for login

Tags: boot-failure

I am new to Linux, never used it before.  I can follow instructions but don't know much about it.  Tried searching for a solution to this but couldn't find one.  I installed Ubuntu 12.04.  It was working fine.  Now when I boot up, I get BIOS splash screen, brief purple screen, then a completely black screen that says:

```
"Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS [Ubuntu name] tty1

[ubuntu name] login:"
```

I can enter in my username and password, then it says:

```
"last login: Mon Sep 10 18:37:03 EDT 2012 on tty1
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-30-generic x86_64)

*Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated
0 updates are security updates"
```

I had this issue, did a fresh install, and then continued having this same problem.  At some point I was also just getting a black screen with a cursor.  I think sometimes all it said was [ok].

Please help - thanks!

Comment: if I press Ctrl+Alt+F7 it goes to a black screen that says [OK] in the top middle and blinking cursor one line below.  once I login it says what I wrote above:

last login: Mon Sep 10 18:37:03 EDT 2012 on tty1 Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-30-generic x86_64)

*Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated 0 updates are security updates"

Comment: I have integrated graphics - intel 2500k

Comment: re: graphics issue -- sometimes after BIOS flash it says something about poor graphics.  Related? If so, thoughts on fixing?

Comment: You can also get debugging info from `startx` into a file by using sudo startx|tee ~/startxdbg.txt` and examining it at your leisure with `nano ~/startxdbg.txt` If you can mount a flashdrive, you can also copy this file to that flash drive and use another computer to inspect it. Make sure you use Wornpad, not Notepad if you re going to use it on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that for some reason the graphics doesn't work, but otherwise the system is fine. Laugh not: what you see is the regular login screen on a Ubuntu server edition, or a typical Unix login screen for many, many years.

This can be for example due to a problem with a graphics driver. There are a few things you can do to correct the problems. After you log in, try the following:

1. Type `startx` at the command prompt. This will, most likely, fail, but it will also print out a reason for the failure.
2. Copy the file /var/log/Xorg.0.log to an USB stick or a Windows partition (your USB stick should work as usual), using command like `cp /var/log/Xorg.0.log /media/XXX`, where XXX is the name of your USB stick. Upload it to http://paste.ubuntu.com.
3. At the minimum, tell us what graphic adapter you have (my guess is: Nvidia)

Comment: Thanks. So, after pressing ctrl+alt+f7, as suggested above, I rebooted.  Then -- ta da -- Ubuntu booted normally.  While that's great, I know that I will have this issue again.  Having said that, i can't now try your suggestion.  I don't have a video card.  Just the integrated intel graphics.

Comment: I did just find that file and pasted it as you suggested. It's here: paste.ubuntu.com/1197686/

Comment: Hm. So there was some problem with your graphic adapter (yes, the on-board graphics adapter counts as such). Next time that happens, make sure to copy the Xorg.0.log file. Actually, you could bother to find the one from the crash -- look into /var/log, there will be a file called Xorg.0.log.old, maybe that is the file from the crash. Compare it with the current log Xorg.0.log; that should give us a hint about what the problem was.

Comment: About the file you pasted: I'm afraid that is the log from when X started correctly. Please post the Xorg.0.log.old file. Every time the graphics starts, a new Xorg.0.log file is started; the old one is moved to Xorg.0.log.old, and the previous Xorg.0.log.old is deleted.

Comment: there is the Xorg.0.log.old file, but I can't open it. Plus it may not matter because I successfully rebooted in between

Comment: If it is the graphics -- what can I do about it?

Comment: open terminal, type `gksudo gedit /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`, what happens? (it should be world readable, so I don't understand what the problem is)

Comment: "If it is the graphics -- what can I do about it?" -- no idea. I've been using Thinkpads with Intel on-board chips for several years now and never had any major problems. See whether the problems appears again.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I posted the Xorg.0.log.old file at paste.ubuntu.com/1197694.  But like I said I think it might not be helpful since I've rebooted successfully.

Comment: Hm, [this log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1197694/) shows a successful X server termination using the power button. OK, close that question now, and next time the same thing happens, make sure you grab the logs first and ask the questions later :-)

Comment: I will, thanks.  Sorry I'm such a noob, but how do I grab the log when I'm at that black screen?

Comment: so I rebooted and am at the black screen now

Comment: Of course, you already explained how to do that

done, and pasted here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1197727/

Comment: See my original answer. If you do not succeed in that (copying Xorg.0.log to paste Ubuntu), do the following magic from the command prompt: `sudo apt-get install curl ; curl -v  --data-urlencode  "content@/var/log/Xorg.0.log" -d "poster=Adam" -d "syntax=text" http://paste.ubuntu.com` - this last command will submit your file directly to [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and it will show you a line like "< Location: http://paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX/".

Comment: Thanks. Just pasted at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1197727/

Comment: Hm, I see no problem here. What happens when you type `startx`?

Comment: flashes screen that says [OK] quickly, then it boots to desktop. Only, at desktop there is no sidebar/panel, etc., so I can't do much of anything

Comment: Doesn't matter. The graphics works. Quit the X (Ctrl-Alt-F1, then Ctrl-C to kill the process) and restart lightdm: `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart`. In any case, your problem is strange, the X seem to work just fine, and I can't help you.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I hope this goes away or someone else can identify the problem!