# Cannot login on my ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, 14.04, login

I left my laptop on for a night while I was downloading some songs but when I woke up it was shutdown and when I tried to restart it I came to the login window normally.

Now when I try to login as a guest a black screen flashes with some message and I am thrown back to the login window again [even as a guest user].

When I try to go to the shell by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>  then login.

I see this error message.

```
--bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: permission denied
```

[image: error image]

I tried to set permissions to my home directory using this command :

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/xor
```

but it didn't helped and I saw the same error again. [as above]

I also tried this command `chown xor:xor .Xauthority` this time no message but problem remained unresolved.

please help me as I am very new to ubuntu as I installed it 2 weeks ago and have no idea what is happening with my system.
[and sorry for bad image]

Comment: try typing restart

Comment: common I am not that idiot...I am rebooting it for 2 days
 That's the first thing every one does.

Comment: Try installing/reinstalling Python3: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3`. (You could press `Tab` a couple of times after python3 to see the latest version and install that.)

Comment: @adil sorry for that use ctrl+alt+f7 or ctrl+alt+f8

Comment: @Creator He couldn't log in using the GUI. My guess is that an error in anything processed by one of the profiles (`/etc/profile`, `.profile`, etc.) causes a GUI login to fail.

Comment: @muru so it might be a problem with lightdm ??

Comment: @adil- take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/186350/on-boot-black-screen-says-ubuntu-12-04-1-lts-ubuntu-name-tty1-and-asks-for

Comment: @Creator, not a problem with lightdm. Here: Try adding this to your `.profile`: `. somefilewhichdoesnotexist`, log out and log back in again.

Comment: @Creator Thanks but..I already tried re-configuring `lightdm` / `gdm` / `lxdm` but no help..

Comment: @muru actually whatever command I try it just gives me `--bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: permission denied` error again.
How ever I can use commands `cd`,`ls`,`cat` ,etc but not ones like `sudo apt-get install` .

Comment: @muru Can you tell me how will I know which file is missing?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: @muru output is : `ls: cannot access /usr/bin/python3: permission denied` however `ls` work else where It seems I dont have permissions over /usr/bin as I can't even `cd` or `ls` there

Comment: What about `ls -l /usr`? If the permissions of `/usr/bin` are bad, we can fix that using `chmod`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old topic, but I had the same issue.  I didn't find a solution to it either, so I decided to add my solution in case someone else is having the same problem.

What I did is actually very easy:

1. I started Live CD
2. Enter in Terminal
3. Mount my disk - `sudo mount /dev/sda1 mnt`
4. Go to `/mnt`
5. Change the privileges - `sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/bin`
6. You are DONE!

I hope this will help!